# mysql do compound indices index individual fields as well?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, compound-index

I have the following MySQL/InnoDB table.  I added a compound index as the primary key on both columns, and I have also added two single column indexes.  With the compound index in place am I getting any performance increase from the single column indexes? or would I be better to drop them?

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `keyword` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyword`,`record_id`),
  KEY `keyword` (`keyword`),
  KEY `record_id` (`record_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `keywords_record_id_records_id` FOREIGN KEY (`record_id`) REFERENCES `records` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If it helps, the main purpose of this table is as a forward index, so this table is exclusively used with record_id `INNER JOIN`ed to the id column of my main record table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *keyword* column is not beneficial, but the *recordid* one definitely is (especially since you're using that heavily on inner joins).  The first column is the main index, the second is only a "tiebreaker", and it's usually no substitute for having another index with that column first.

Think of it like this ... say you have a list of people's info, ordered first by name, then by phone number.  If you need to look up a person's name, this list is more than fine; you don't need a second one ordered by name only.  But if you need to look up someone by phone number, then this name-then-phone ordered list is just as useless as if there were no order at all; you would need another list ordered by phone number first.